# Как исправить ошибку System.Net.Sockets.SocketException C#?

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер

Всем привет. Пишу программу на С# клиент-сервер, выдает такую ошибку: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: "Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа". Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это связано и как исправить?[image: скрин ошибки]

Comment: Добрый вечер, если хотите добавит код, то делайте это, используя функцию {} в редакторе текста, если же необходимо вставить картинку, то обрезайте её до нужного места, спасибо

Comment: поменял порт на 1024 и заработало

Answer (score 1):

Перезапустить VS от имени администратора. Если не помогло, смотреть что этот порт заняло.